# Permutations of repetition for selection from a set of 11 colours with 5 sections to colour

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations, extremal-combinatorics

I am attempting a generative art project of which I am creating all possible permutations of a template using 11 colours. There are 5 sections that can be coloured.

I have calculated the possible permutations to be 11^5 giving 161,051 different possibilities. I wish to grade them in rarity via their statistical probability of occurring,

i.e all 5 colours the same being the rarest, next being 4 the same, 3 etc etc.

So essentially I am looking for all ways to mix colours = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k] with pieces = [r, s, x, y, z]

Doing so has returned the following numbers:

- 11 of 5/5 the same colour
- 550 of 4/5 ...
- 11,000 of 3/5 ...
- 94,050 of 2/5 ...
- 55,440 of 1/5 ...

And I am coming up short with being able to calculate the odds of it returning a final result within each bracket (my maths is a little rusty) and initially thought that the values would grow larger within each bracket as the number of the same colours reduced, but as can be seen there is more in the second to last than the last. I'm thinking this may be due to combining two such as 3/5 also having the possibility to also contain a 2/5 or two 1/5 separate permutations within it?

Would anyone be able to help me calculate the correct probabilities of each tier, as currently I'm getting more in the uncommon category than the common one?

If so thank you in advance!

Comment: These numbers are actually correct, as long as you intend to count the maximum number of appearances of a single color, e.g. the "2/5" case counts all arrangements with 2 of one color, but not 3 or more.

Comment: oooh thank you for the answer! I do intend on basing upon the maximum appearance, though may I ask you as a collectible item would it seem obscure to have uncommon containing more than common? and also would doing so based on the maximum appearance alter the odds of obtaining one from the uncommon class?

Comment: It might indeed seem a little odd if the supposedly "uncommon" arrangements (which are actually more common) appear more than the "common" ones. I'm not sure what your second question is asking exactly (forgive me, please!), but one way you could make the probabilities align more with intuition is to increase the number of colors. Then the $1/5$ arrangement becomes much more common in comparison.

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm thinking about it seeming odd. And sorry wasnt clear, but i mean is it statistically more likely to achieve 2/5 colours being the same, or 1/5 being the same? (I'm assuming now that 2/5 is more likely than 1/5 but not sure if im just thinking about it incorrectly)

And yes that would be much more intuitive but im intending to put out each and every combination, so would that mean id just run into the same problem at some other level of combinations? 

Again, thanks for the time and consideration

Comment: The 2/5 outcome is indeed more likely than the 1/5 outcome for $11$ colors; I can post an explanation of each of the counts as an answer if you'd like. As the number of colors increases, though, the 1/5 outcome will become more likely. For example, with more than $16$ colors, the probability of achieving a 1/5 outcome exceeds $1/2$.

Comment: ahh yes this what i was kinda thinking but unable to explain clearly haha, like as the width of the search tree gets bigger the possibility goes up. (IF it wouldnt be too much effort for you i would really love that just as a way to grasp it more clearly) and dammit that makes life a lot easier for the project statistically but also harder in terms of how many there would be haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an explanation for why each of the counts is correct, case-by-case.

$5/5$: if all of the sections are the same color, there are $11$ ways to pick the color and therefore $\boxed{11}$ permutations.

$4/5$: there are $11$ ways to pick Color $A$, the one that occupies $4$ sections; $10$ ways to pick some other Color $B$; and $5$ ways to pick the lone section colored with Color $B$, giving $11\cdot10\cdot5 = \boxed{550}$ permutations.

$3/5$: there are two cases. Either there are three colors $A$, $B$, and $C$, such that $A$ colors $3$ sections and $B$ and $C$ color one each, or there are two colors $A$ and $B$, where $A$ colors $3$ sections and $B$ colors two sections.

In the first case, there are $11$ ways to pick Color $A$, $10$ ways to pick Color $B$, and $9$ ways to pick Color $C$. There are $5$ ways to choose the section with Color $B$ and $4$ ways to choose the section with Color $C$, and the other sections can be left for Color $A$. However, this double-counts by a factor of $2$, since we can reach a permutation twice by swapping our choices of $B$ and $C$ and swapping the sections we choose. Therefore, this case includes $11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot5\cdot4 \cdot (1/2) = 9{,}900$ permutations.

In the second case, there are $11\cdot10$ ways to pick Colors $A$ and $B$, and $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to pick the $2$ sections to be colored by Color $B$. Therefore, this case includes $11\cdot10\cdot10=1{,}100$ permutations, yielding a total of $\boxed{11{,}000}$ permutations for $3/5$.

$1/5$: We have to pick a different color for each section, so there are $11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7 = \boxed{55{,}440}$ of these permutations.

$2/5$: this is just all the other cases, so there are $161{,}051-11-550-11{,}000-55{,}440=\boxed{94{,}050}$ of these.

---

In general, this counter-intuitiveness only arises because there are just not enough colors for duplicates to be uncommon. On the low end–if there are only $5$ colors, for example–it'd seem pretty unlikely to manage to hit a different color each time. If there were $4$ colors, it'd be outright impossible! Meanwhile, on the high end–say, if there are $1{,}000$ colors–hitting the same color twice would be pretty unlikely. So, the "crossover" point, where using the same color twice becomes less likely than using different colors for each section, is somewhere in the middle, and it just so happens that $11$ colors is *not* enough to make duplicating colors less likely.

In fact, we can find the number of colors such that using a different color each time would be more frequent than using the same color twice. The probability of using all different colors is $$ \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{n}. $$ (To see why, there are $n$ ways to pick the first section's color, $n-1$ ways to pick the second section's color, etc.) Numerically solving $$ \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{n} > \frac{1}{2}$$ yields $n > 16.01$, so you'd have to have at least $17$ colors for those "common" arrangements to be more likely than not.

Comment: Thank you heaps for that, makes way more sense already and I'm sure after a couple more read throughs it'll be stuck in there for me haha. I upvoted you but im too new for it to count haha but again again thank you heaps!